# Proper way to check for existence of field in Javascript (or frameworks)?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I suppose this applies to all JS in general but what would be a proper way to rewrite this computed method to ensure it wouldn't fail if a field wasn't available?

```
computed() {
   isVerified() {
        return this.name.info.is_valid;
   }
}
```

I can do it but it would be quite wordy:

```
computed() {
   isVerified() {
        if (this.name && this.name.info && this.name.info.is_valid) {
           return true;
        } else {
           return false;
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: There's a new syntax for this (`a?.b`), but you can already shorten that by simply returning the expression itself: `return this.name && this.name.info && this.name.info.is_valid;`

Comment: thanks @ChrisG ...can you explain more about the new syntax or point me in a direction where I can read about that?

Comment: It's basically `return this.name?.info?.is_valid;`, preventing a null exception if a property doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combining [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) with [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_Coalescing_Operator) seems appropriate in your case.

```
computed() {
  isVerified() {
    return this.name?.info?.is_valid ?? false;
  }
}
```

If any of `this.name`, `this.name.info` or `this.name.info.is_valid` is `null` or `undefined`, `isVerified` returns `false` (boolean). Otherwise it returns the current value of `this.name.info.is_valid`, whatever it may be (including any falsey values other than `null` or `undefined`. i.e: `0`, `''`, `NaN`).

---

Keep in mind that, for the time being, the following list of browsers have no support for the two operators:

- Internet Explorer
- Firefox for Android
- Opera for Android
- Samsung Internet

---

See their current implementation status on caniuse.com:

- [optional chaining](https://caniuse.com/?search=optional%20chaining)
- [nullish coalescing operator](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_operators_nullish_coalescing),

---

Note on latest Vue 2 (`v2.6.11`) usage: both operators only work inside components (methods, computed, hooks, etc...), but they error if used directly in templates.
Haven't tested in Vue 3, but I expect them to work (they're valid TypeScript operators as of [v3.7](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html)).

For purists, here is the output of

```
function isValid(name) {
  return name?.info?.is_valid ?? false;
}
```

...in Babel:

```js
"use strict";

function isValid(name) {
  var _name$info$is_valid, _name$info;

  return (_name$info$is_valid = name === null || name === void 0
          ? void 0
          : (_name$info = name.info) === null || _name$info === void 0
            ? void 0
            : _name$info.is_valid
         ) !== null && _name$info$is_valid !== void 0
          ? _name$info$is_valid
          : false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

javascript is nice and boolean in your first 2 variables, but are you referencing django in your is_valid function?

```
    if (this.name && this.name.info && this.name.info.is_valid) {
       return true;
    } else {
       return false;
    }
```